# Sending JavaScript file with varying data on http call

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I am interested in finding out how Google Tag Manager sends the tags to the website that is to be tracked for a similar functionality I need on my tracking script. On inspecting the flow through DevTools, I see that the gtm.js file is loaded from an http call and it contains the tag info like so: [image]

These tags are unique to the id in the http call eg. ?id=GTM-XXXXX
I cannot figure out how these tags are present in script based on the ID,
for example if another website calls the gtm.js with a different id, it gets the tags related to that id.
Are there different gtm.js scripts for each id? Or do they do some changes to the script on the backend based on the ID before sending the response?
Any ideas on how this might be accomplished are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the "id" query parameter, Google's backend returns a script dynamically customized to that ID.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jon, much appreciated. That's just what I wanted to understand, as in, how one might dynamically change the contents of a script? Sorry if the question sounds too broad or too beginner like.

Comment: "Dynamically" might not be the correct word (it suggests that the script is built on the fly when the file is requested). GTM bundles all tags in a javascript file as configured in the GTM UI, and then returns the "compiled" file by id.